# createTextNode without htmlentities

Tags: javascript, html-entities, createtextnode

Consider the following snippet:

```
var t = "<span>Hello world</span>";
var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
range.deleteContents();
range.insertNode(document.createTextNode(t));
```

How can I avoid replacing `t` with htmlentities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By not creating a textnode. Instead use [range.pasteHTML](http://help.dottoro.com/ljnuatqw.php).

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't work in Firefox, but I found this function which does the job: http://groups.google.com/group/google-ajax-discuss/browse_thread/thread/80005bae70a63481/61d3f7c99ff6bd31

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a textnode.

```
var t = document.createElement('span');
t.textContent = 'Hello world';
var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
range.deleteContents();
range.insertNode(t);
```